# tableview crashed when press back button of navigation controller?

Tags: iphone

the **`numberOfRowsInSection`** returns 0 when i press `navigationcontroller's` back button,
but  **`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`**  is called when i put break point...application crashes  ..any help please?

Answer (score 0):

Try to make the **numberOfRowsInSection** method return 1

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should set the delegate of tableview to nil, dealloc before releasing your table view like this:

```
- (void)dealloc{

[myTableView setDelegate:nil];
[myTableView release];
myTableView = nil;

}
```

besides are you trying to reload the table in `viewWillDisappear`, if yes you should avoid it and find a workaround for this.

Hope this helps.